# UTF-8 Chars not Passing Through SQL Script

Tags: sql, unicode, utf-8

I have written a simple CASE for a Language switch for some Customer Data, as below

```
CASE WHEN KN.SPRAS='E' THEN 'English'
 WHEN KN.SPRAS='D' THEN 'Deutsch'
 WHEN KN.SPRAS='1' THEN '中文'            --Chinese
 WHEN KN.SPRAS='F' THEN 'Français'
 WHEN KN.SPRAS='J' THEN '日本語'           --Japanese
 WHEN KN.SPRAS='I' THEN 'Italiano'
 WHEN KN.SPRAS='S' THEN 'Español'
 WHEN KN.SPRAS='P' THEN 'Português'
 WHEN KN.SPRAS='3' THEN '한국어'           --Korean
 WHEN KN.SPRAS='L' THEN 'Polski'
 WHEN KN.SPRAS='O' THEN 'Norsk'
 WHEN KN.SPRAS='V' THEN 'Svenska'
 WHEN KN.SPRAS='K' THEN 'Dansk'
 WHEN KN.SPRAS='N' THEN 'Nederlands'
 ELSE '' END As Language
```

Upon execution, it only passes ??? to the output, when it encounters non-western characters, which tells me that the UTF-8 encoding in the script window is somehow being lost in the output. The output retains the rest of the UTF-8 for the customer data, in the name and address and such, but loses it in this piece of custom code. How do I get the Language column to be UTF-8 Compliant?

Comment: Try a national character literal, `N'日本語'`.

Comment: But you should really store all these values in a languages table, and JOIN instead,

Comment: The national character literal did it. Thanks!!

Comment: There *is* a language T-Table, but it's not in this instance, so... yeah. Thanks again!